# junit | autowired components in main is null

Tags: spring, junit, autowired, spring-config

I have a class defined in src/main/java:

```
Class A{
    @Autowired 
    B b; 
    public void method1() {}
}
```

The corresponding test class is:

```
Class ATest {
    A a; 
    @Test
    public void method1Test() {}
}
```

B is null when ATest is unit tested. (run as junit test).

I only have spring-context library, and not spring boot application. Further, I have defined `@ComponentScan(basePackage="com")` and class A is inside of the same package.

Please let me know how to unit test in this scenario.

Comment: Did my answer helped? Do you need more info?

Answer (score 1):

For Spring dependencies I add to test class `@Spy` and `@Autowired`:

```
@Spy
@Autowired
private B b;
```

`B` will be available when testing `A`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you define classes that are not unit tests in resource directory?

Comment: sorry, it is src/main/java not resources

Answer (score 0):

Mockito provides option to create spy on real objects. When spy is called, then actual method of real object is called.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
Class ATest {

    @Syp
    B b;

    @Test
    public void method1Test() {}
}
```